# Why does Visual Studio removes attributes when i compile a DLL?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, odin-inspector

I am compiling a DLL for Unity with Visual Studio Community 2019. I am using Odin Inspector in Unity, therefore i referenced Sirenix.OdinInspector.Attributes in VisualStudio/assemblies. After compiling the DLL and using or opening the DLL in Unity i can see that the (odin) attribute [HideReferenceObjectPicker] was removed from the compiled code.

Is there a way to keep this attribute in the compiled DLL?

Comment: id have thought because odin is an editor only system? why ywould you need it at runtime?

Comment: The DLL i am compiling is some sort of library for an entity system. I show these entities also in the Unity Editor, for balancing purposes. Hmm, maybe using a DLL is the wrong way here.

Comment: You would probably want 2 dlls, one for runtime and one for editor.  The editor dll can reference things from the runtime dll, but not the other way around.